# ionRangeSlider - get range value to hidden form input field

Tags: jquery, forms, range, hidden-field

how to show range value in hidden input field  using jquery 
range code

```js
$("#range").ionRangeSlider({
  grid: true,
  from: 1,
  to: 6,
  values: [
    "", "Tenth",
    "Diploma", "Twelth", "Graduate",
    "PostGraduate", "P.hd"
  ]
});
```

```html
<input type="range" id="range" value="" name="range" />
```

show in that hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" id="f4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need you use the `onChange` event and I assume you want to set the value to the text value (`"Tenth","Diploma","Twelth", "Graduate","PostGraduate","P.hd"`) which you will need to use `data.from_value`:-

```js
$("#range").ionRangeSlider({
  grid: true,
  from: 1,
  to: 6,
  values: [
    "", "Tenth",
    "Diploma", "Twelth", "Graduate",
    "PostGraduate", "P.hd"
  ],
  onChange: function(data) {
    alert(data.from_value);

    $('#f4').val(data.from_value);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.4/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.4/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.4/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" id="range" value="" name="range" />

<input type="hidden" id="f4" />
```